# Cannot return a array of generic type from a method in a class

Tags: java

I am implementing my own generic Linked List class and it has a instance method called `toArray` that make a array copy of the linked list and return it. However, whenever I try to call that method on an instance I keep getting error message "SLList.this cannot be referenced from a static context". I searched for it for a bit and some people said that it was because I did not call that method on an instance, but I indeed did.

Here is the class:

```
public class SLList<ElemType>{

    private class StuffNode{
        public ElemType item;
        public StuffNode next;
    
        public StuffNode(ElemType i, StuffNode n){
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }
    }
    /** The first item of a list(if it exists) is at sentinel.next*/
    private StuffNode sentinel;
    private int size;

        public ElemType[] toArray(){
           ElemType[] arr =(ElemType[]) new Object[this.size];
           StuffNode ptr = this.sentinel;
           int i = 0;
           while(ptr.next != null){
               arr[i] = ptr.next.item;
               ptr = ptr.next;
               i++;
        }
           return arr;
    }

}
```

It has some method like `addLast, addFirst` and they have no problem.

```
        public static void main(String[] args){
           SLList<Integer> x = new SLList<>(3);
           x.addLast(4);
           x.addFirst(1);
           ElemType[] arr = x.toArray();
    }
```

`ElemType[] arr = x.toArray();` is the line where I keep getting error message, and I have used a online Java visualizer to confirm that method works just fine, I just have problem returning the result from it

Comment: make it a public static class

Comment: you probably created your SLList inside your main class. If you want to use it from static context you need to make it a static class: "public static class SLList"
Or you can do: "new Main().new SLList<>(3);"

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SLList<Integer> x = new Main2().new SLList<>(3);
        x.addLast(4);
        x.addFirst(1);
        Integer[] arr = x.toArray();
    }

    public class SLList<ElemType> {
        private class StuffNode {
            public ElemType item;
            public StuffNode next;

            public StuffNode(ElemType i, StuffNode n) {
                item = i;
                next = n;
            }
        }
    
        public SLList(ElemType n) {
            // Some code for constructor
        }
    
        public void addFirst(ElemType n) {
            // Some code
        }

        public void addLast(ElemType n) {
            // Some code
        }

        /**
         * The first item of a list(if it exists) is at sentinel.next
         */
        private StuffNode sentinel;
        private int size;

        public ElemType[] toArray() {
            ElemType[] arr = (ElemType[]) new Object[this.size];
            StuffNode ptr = this.sentinel;
            int i = 0;
            while (ptr.next != null) {
                arr[i] = ptr.next.item;
                ptr = ptr.next;
                i++;
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SLList<Integer> x = new SLList<>(3);
        x.addLast(4);
        x.addFirst(1);
        Integer[] arr = x.toArray();
    }

    // INSERT A STATIC HERE
    public static class SLList<ElemType> {
        private class StuffNode {
            public ElemType item;
            public StuffNode next;

            public StuffNode(ElemType i, StuffNode n) {
                item = i;
                next = n;
            }
        }

        public SLList(ElemType n) {
            // Some code for constructor
        }

        public void addFirst(ElemType n) {
            // Some code
        }

        public void addLast(ElemType n) {
            // Some code
        }

        /**
         * The first item of a list(if it exists) is at sentinel.next
         */
        private StuffNode sentinel;
        private int size;

        public ElemType[] toArray() {
            ElemType[] arr = (ElemType[]) new Object[this.size];
            StuffNode ptr = this.sentinel;
            int i = 0;
            while (ptr.next != null) {
                arr[i] = ptr.next.item;
                ptr = ptr.next;
                i++;
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }
}
```